# eazyBI Error: Cannot import custom fields with the same name: "Sprint Status"

Tags: jira

After i update the eazyBI plugin from 4.1.2 to 4.3.0, it cannot import the jira data again. The eazybi-queues.log is following:

```
2017-06-12 19:44:50 +0800 INFO: [application_import] *** got:  
SourceApplication id=2 perform_import()
2017-06-12 19:44:55 +0800 INFO: [application_import] account 1 : get_jira_server_info
2017-06-12 19:44:55 +0800 INFO: [application_import] account 1 : get_custom_fields
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR: [application_import] account 1 : RuntimeError: Cannot import custom fields with the same name: "Sprint Status"
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_application/custom_fields_import_methods.rb:119:in `validate_selected_custom_fields'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_application/custom_fields_import_methods.rb:40:in `get_custom_fields'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_application/jira_application.rb:810:in `import_all_rows'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_application/base_application.rb:244:in `perform_import'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/account.rb:110:in `use_dwh'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/dwh.rb:116:in `__ensure__'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/account.rb:108:in `use_dwh'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_application/base_application.rb:243:in `perform_import'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_import_common.rb:61:in `disable_all_tracing'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_application/base_application.rb:241:in `perform_import'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/app/models/source_application.rb:913:in `perform_import'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/private_async_queue_processor.rb:33:in `on_message'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/account_lock.rb:5:in `async_around_filter'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/private_async_queue_helpers.rb:66:in `async_around_filter'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/account_lock.rb:5:in `__ensure__'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/account_lock.rb:4:in `async_around_filter'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/private_async_queue_processor.rb:32:in `on_message'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/private_async_queue_processor.rb:25:in `on_message'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from vendor/gems/eazybi/lib/private_async_queue_processor.rb:22:in `__ensure__'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from config/initializers/work_queues.rb:10:in `(root)'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/girl_friday-0.11.2/lib/girl_friday/work_queue.rb:147:in `start'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/rubinius-actor-0.0.2/lib/rubinius/actor.rb:88:in `spawn_link'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/rubinius-actor-0.0.2/lib/rubinius/actor.rb:71:in `spawn'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/rubinius-actor-0.0.2/lib/rubinius/actor.rb:214:in `initialize'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/rubinius-actor-0.0.2/lib/rubinius/actor.rb:373:in `watchdog'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/rubinius-actor-0.0.2/lib/rubinius/actor.rb:214:in `initialize'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 ERROR:         from /usr/local/JIRA/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix/felix-cache/bundle197/version0.0/plugin_7412032927367486283_eazybi-jira-4.3.0_1496748581000.jar-lib/0/META-INF/gem.home/gems/rubinius-actor-0.0.2/lib/rubinius/actor.rb:68:in `spawn'
2017-06-12 19:44:56 +0800 INFO: [application_import] *** done: SourceApplication id=2 perform_import()
```

I found eazyBI add an Additional Sprint dimensions in 4.3.0, href: https://docs.eazybi.com/display/EAZYBIJIRA/JIRA+Software+custom+fields . Maybe it's a clue...
How can i fix this problem? My JIRA version is 6.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

After adding sprint information eazyBI treats "Sprint Status" as a reserved field name. You can change the name by adding this to advanced settings:

```
[jira.customfield_NNNNN]
name = "My Sprint Status"
```